# p:pickList doesn't update the source and target

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have been accessing the `p:picklist` for the first time and I am facing a issue where I am not able to get source and target values updated as in the `p:picklist` ui. I am using list of `DualListModel<String>`. Here is the code..

Please help me. 
Thanks for the help!

`code.xhtml`

```
<p:dataTable value="#{updateSiteObj.dsList}" var="pickListObjDS" >
    <p:column headerText="DS">
        <p:pickList id="pojoPickListDSID" value="#{pickListObjDS}" var="ds"  itemValue="#{ds}" itemLabel="#{ds}"  showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" style="border-color: white!important" onTransfer="ajaxSubmit3()">  
            <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="targetCaption">To be removed</f:facet>  
        </p:pickList>
        <p:remoteCommand action="#{updateSiteObj.onDSTransfer}" name="ajaxSubmit3"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

`UpdateSite.java`

```
@ManagedBean(name = "updateSiteObj")
@SessionScoped
public class UpdateSite {

    private List<DualListModel<String>> dsList = new ArrayList<DualListModel<String>>();

    public List<DualListModel<String>> getDsList() {
        return dsList;
    }

    public void setDsList(List<DualListModel<String>> dsList) {
        this.dsList = dsList;
    }

    public String updateSiteDetails() {

        ds.add(sg.getPrimaryDSID());
        if (sg.getSecondaryDSID() != null) {
            ds.add(sg.getSecondaryDSID());
        }

        System.out.print("DS:" + sg.getPrimaryDSID() + "=>" + sg.getSecondaryDSID());
        DualListModel<String> tempDS = new DualListModel<String>();
        tempDS.setSource(ds);
        dsList.add(tempDS);
        return "someSite?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public void onDSTransfer() {
        System.out.print("DSTransfer");
        for (DualListModel<String> str1 : dsList) {
            System.out.print("RemovedLBEntry:");
            for (String dsName1 : str1.getTarget()) {
                System.out.print("RemovedLB:" + dsName1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call `onDSTransfer` after moving the values from source panel to target panel in `picklist` UI doesn't show any value from target.

Comment: Where are the columns for your picklist?

Comment: i don get u.. columns will be added based on item label, which is already there

Comment: I think it is converter issue. Please check your conventer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `update="@all"` in `p:remoteCommand`.

You are doing a ajax call and not updating your UI.

```
<p:remoteCommand action="#{updateSiteObj.onDSTransfer}" name="ajaxSubmit3" update="@all"/>
```

Comment: Using `update="@all"` for basic normal updates is bad practice. This should only be used in special case, this not being one of them in my opinion. Find something else that can be updated...